# How large is the Group Delay Dispersion for ultrafast light pulse into glass if the refractive index changes linearly?

Tags: optics, refraction

If an ideal ultrafast pulse with the duration of 1 cycle of light is propagating from air (with n = 1) into glass in the direction normal to the interface, Im also assuming the refractive index n of the glass changes in a linear fashion from 1.64 at 740 nm to 1.71 at 860 nm. How large is the Group Delay Dispersion after 1 cm (into the glass). Also how would i determine the temporal extent of the pulse?